# Web App Generator

Tags: application-development

I encounter an error message each time I try to submit a web app for mobile using the Ubuntu Web App generator. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there an issue with it right now?

Regards,

Antoine

Comment: It shows each time this page encountered an error, don't worry - we have been notified. Please accept our apologies. I have this message since a week...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually the developer of this tool and this bug is caused by an unexpected change of server infrastructure. The fix is waiting to be deployed by a team from Canonical who seems to have its plate already quite full. Thanks for your patience.

Also, you can find a working version at http://developer.staging.ubuntu.com/webapp-generator/ :-)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work from Ubuntu browser on the Ubuntu phone.